# What happened to the $10/month plan for 10 users on Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I was just about to sign up for Stack Overflow for Teams for $10/month for our 10 users, but I don't see that pricing anywhere.  What happened? I just got my company on board with the idea, now I can't get approval with this new pricing schema.

The $10 for 10 users strategy was great because we could grow into a larger usage as our team grew.

Comment: The deal I'm seeing right now for Teams is [$5/user/month](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing), so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: All 10 users were supposed to cost only $10/month (effectively $1/user/month), and then $5/user/month thereafter. That pricing seems to be gone :(

Comment: So, before: `max(5 * (N - 8), 10)`. After: `5 * N`. Definitely "simpler", and always worse for all teams, other than team size 1. :)

Comment: @SteveBennett This is my memory serving me, but it may have been `N > 10 ? (5 * N) : 10`, which would explain both of Alex's points because the old pricing model would drastically jump from $10/month to $55/month on the 11th user!

Comment: Oh! Completely different. Misunderstood "thereafter". Yeah, pricing cliffs are the worst. (I'm on something like 30 Slack's and only one of them is paid.)

Comment: I get the *cliff*, but raising the price to 500% of the original doesn't sounds like a fair solution to me.

Comment: For 10 to 500, is a 400% raised. 
That's not bad, 
Only a 0.07(7%) on the MartinShkreli ladder (the 5500% raise ladder). For comparaison Venezuela inflation was  10 MartinShkreli last year.

Comment: @xdtTransform I didn't write *by* 500% but *to*. 

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, as of April 30, 2019 we've updated our pricing for [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing) to be a single per-user rate for all users with no tiers or cliffs.

As part of the original launch in 2018 we offered a tiered pricing plan where the first ten users were a flat $10 and then individual pricing for users beyond those first ten. Since it was a new product, we made a bunch of assumptions (including around pricing) with the launch of Teams. Watching it over the next year, we found that there were two problems with this pricing plan:

1. People were confused by this pricing setup
2. It created some weird psychological incentives as Teams crossed the 10 user threshold that actually discouraged adoption and created churn among customers at exactly the time that adoption was increasing.

Based on those learnings and our goal of trying to create as sustainable and useful a business for Teams as possible, we decided to simplify our pricing model with the single per-user rate.

*(PS: Hi! I'm the GM of Teams here at Stack Overflow)*

**EDIT - 5/3/2019**: Adding one clarification - this updated pricing only applies to ***new*** subscriptions.  Existing contracts maintain their original pricing.

Comment: Hi! It's too bad that I started reviewing SO as an option about a week ago just to be bit by the pricing model change! I found the $10/month schema very familiar (a la Atlassian) and I appreciate the ability to assess the platform with that model (maybe there's something missing that customers were hoping to see). For now, I'll just have to accept it as a paradigm shift and use the 2 week trial given to me to see if SO can be helpful to our dev team, instead of the longer timeline I was planning for with $10/month pricing.

Comment: So the rate for 10 user teams has effectively quintupled then, though.

Comment: -1 - You did not include a reference or even state the new pricing plan.  So what is the price for say 10 users now?  If it has gone up we won't be renewing!  Wow price is now 50 bucks a month (for 10 users).  That is 600 bucks a year compared to 120.  This is a disgrace.  Celery used to be 79cents  at my local grocer, its now upto 4.99...they blame it on cold weather...there's always some excuse to make money.

Comment: Are current customers grandfathered in to the old pricing?

Comment: @JonH OP didn't ask what the new pricing plan was. He asked what happened to the old one. This answers that quite well. If you're downvoting because you don't like paying more for a product, well, at least be transparent about that instead of acting like Alex' answer somehow falls short of addressing the OP.

Comment: Guys, don't get so hung up on the fact that SO _very generously_ offered an _incredible_ deal during the first year, and now it's going away. Per-user pricing is _extremely_ common for SaaS for the exact two reasons that Alex mentioned. Be happy that the pricing lasted as long as it did and understand that current pricing is still very fair given the value provided.

Comment: I don't have any views about pricing. However I would urge all folks frustrated with the change to make their remarks constructive, and not direct unpleasant and hostile remarks towards Stack Overflow employees.

Comment: @misteroptimist yes, the updated pricing only applies to NEW customers - existing contracts will continue at the original pricing they signed up at

Comment: *Celery used to be 79cents at my local grocer, its now upto 4.99...they blame it on cold weather...there's always some excuse to make money.* It was the celery juicing fad, it's still a thing but it was huge last year. The recommended dose to drink  daily was 16 ounces, but it has to be made fresh every day, it can't be kept in the fridge (so they say). Apparently the price of celery skyrocketed. The power of suggestion and false promises; cancer cure, weight loss, ...