# Is Teams a free product for teams with fewer than 11 members?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, pricing

I hope this is not too dense a question.

I read a few questions regarding Teams pricing:

- [What happened to the $10/month plan for 10 users on Stack Overflow for Teams?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384467/what-happened-to-the-10-month-plan-for-10-users-on-stack-overflow-for-teams)
- [Is Stack Overflow for Teams' pricing model really a 500% increase when you have more than 10 users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382306/is-stack-overflow-for-teams-pricing-model-really-a-500-increase-when-you-have)
- [SO Teams ad shows a higher price than expected (the real price is lower!)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370422/so-teams-ad-shows-a-higher-price-than-expected-the-real-price-is-lower)

But when I get to the [pricing page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing) I now see this:

> [image]

Has the pricing structure been updated again, and is "Basic" now effectively a free product if you have less than 11 users on the team, and you would only pay from the 11th users onwards?

If the answer it's simply "yes", my apologies for the dumb question. The product already went a couple of pricing changes since its inception, understandably, and what I thought I knew does not seem to match what I read now. I'd like to know if I'm not misinterpreting things.

Comment: I'd guess that you pay a flat $5 per month (whether you have 1 user or 10), then additional for each user above 10. Or at least, that's how it reads to me.

Comment: That's certainly not how it reads to me. Hence the question. If it's the way you suggest, the copy should be greatly clarified, IMO.

Comment: Agreed. Each time I read it I come to a different conclusion.

Comment: If I understand anything about uncertainty, the only way to resolve it would be to kill a cat inside a box.

Comment: If you click on get started, you land here: https://stackoverflow.com/teams#get-started, which states: "First 10 users free". Not really much uncertainty about that.

Comment: Thanks @Luuklag. Yes, it's basically what it reads on the pricing page. I do not believe it's unclear, it's simply that it contradicts the previous pricing announcement, and I want to confirm that this is an actual change, and not an error in copy. These things can happen. I'm aware it can look like a very stupid question, since reading the prices literally does not leave much room for doubt; but I'd still like a confirmation, which I think could also be useful for other users.

Comment: I know a couple of circles that would jump at this seemly opportunity and ask questions later. BTW, I think the kicks here is that they expect smaller groups being paid off by big companies. The only thing that confuses me is the 14 day trial.

Comment: Agreed @Braiam. The 14 days thing was part of what didn’t make it 100% clear cut.

Comment: Says 25 people for me

Comment: Yes @Aequitas. It changed yet again after this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [Stack Overflow for Teams is now free for up to 50 users](https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/teams-free?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=campaign-28&utm_content=post-3), forever.

- No credit card is required to start your Team, and it’s free forever.
- Our Free plan includes ChatOps integrations to Slack and Microsoft Teams.
- We have invested in a guided onboarding process to help admins and users experience value quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 41):

This is not a pricing structure change, but rather a special promotion running only for the month of September, after which the first 10 users free promotion will disappear from that page.

If you create a Team during September, you will not be billed at all for the first 10 users on the Team for as long as the Team is active*. You will start getting billed $5/user for the 11th user onwards (when billed annually), immediately once an 11th user joins the Team. So if you have 10 or fewer users on the Team, your bill would simply be $0 (note though that we still require a valid credit card to be entered regardless).

This promotion only applies to the Basic plan; it does not apply to the Business or Enterprise plans.

Also keep in mind that the 14 day trial is a completely separate concept. The entire Team, no matter how many users join, will always be free for the first 14 days.

<sub>* Active simply means that the Team still exists and hasn't been cancelled.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Animuson! I'll let some interested parties know of this!

Comment: Why so you require a credit card if you know the bill is going to be $0?

Comment: @Robert The card gets charged the moment an 11th person joins the team and the bill is no longer $0, assuming the trial has ended. It doesn't make sense to sit around waiting for an admin to come enter credit card info after the 11th person has joined or forbidding an 11th person until that is done. Instead, every account requires a card on file.

Comment: I think you guys could benefit from making very clear that it's a special promotion

Comment: @RobertColumbia This is like 10,000% standard marketing promotion. It’s a freemium model. This is not unique or special to SO. I think what you’re feeling is yet another small pivot of SO turning towards a more standard corporate model, and away from the heady days when the company and the community were blended and inseparable. My guess is all the signals we’ve seen, especially change in CEO, means SO’s investors and shareholders weren’t seeing the return they wanted, so they implemented a more tried-and-true formulaic model. SE, Inc is just a generic American corporation now.

Comment: If I add less than 10 users in September, can I add the rest after September for free?

Comment: @Nucleus Yes you can. Doesn't pay attention to when users are added. Essentially what it's doing is looking at total number of users and subtracting 10 when creating the bill amount.

Comment: @animuson Alright, thanks.

Comment: Now it says "first 25 users free". Is that an October promotion?

Comment: it is November and it still says it. so @legoscia it was not October only :)

Comment: "Please enter your billing information to finish creating your Team on the Basic plan. Your first 25 will always be free. If you exceed 25 users, you will not be billed until the 14 day free trial is over, and you can cancel anytime. "  -- It now says that your first 25 will always be free on the billing page.

Comment: So, now it's January and it no longer lists any free user. Is there any way to get it? Or it's just gone and the only way is to pay for all the users?

Comment: @EndermanAPM Unfortunately, no. The promotion is expired and it's not possible to apply it to a new account.

Comment: @animuson is it possible that there will be another promotion eventually?